# How to detect user interaction on a Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, user-interaction

I can detect user interaction in an activity with this code:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
}
```

But Android Dialog has no method like that. And I couldn't find the way to handle it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried if you get onUserInteraction events in your activity while the dialog is shown ? If yes, you can track if the dialog is shown and handle the case accordingly.

Comment: I couldn't get events in my activity.

Comment: Have you any solution to this ??

Comment: @Burak Do have any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppCompatActivity styled as dialog with style instead of regular Android Dialog

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
...
</style>
```

Then you could use functionality of Activity class

You also should use following onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.abc_alert_dialog_material);
}
```

To make it behave like dialog you manually need to find all the views you need to attach click listeners to each button.

Here are some IDs you may find useful:

```
@BindView(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.topPanel)
protected ViewGroup mTopPanel;
@BindView(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.contentPanel)
protected ViewGroup mContentPanel;
@BindView(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.customPanel)
protected ViewGroup mCustomPanel;
@BindView(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.custom)
protected ViewGroup mCustomViewContainer;
@BindView(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.textSpacerNoButtons)
protected View mTextSpacer;
@BindView(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.buttonPanel)
protected ButtonBarLayout mButtonPanel;

@BindView(android.R.id.message)
protected TextView mMessage;
@BindView(android.R.id.button1)
protected Button mPositiveButton;
@BindView(android.R.id.button2)
protected Button mNegativeButton;
@BindView(android.R.id.button3)
protected Button mNeutralButton;
```

(Butterknife annotations included, if you are not using Butterknife just use findViewById with each annotation from @BindView(id))